# How can I make SonarQube ignore certain lines in files as duplicated?

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube shows duplicated code. Certain things in my code that it flags as duplicates are not really duplicates. For example, I have a copyright statement at the beginning of each c sharp file. SonarQube is flagging this as a duplicated line of code. How can I tell SonarQube to just globally ignore this line?

Comment: Which programming language? Are they written as comments? Because normally Sonarqube ignores comments.

Comment: I have a copyright statement as a comment and SonarQube is flagging it.